# Non-additive-subtractive prime sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations, closed-form

Call the following a NON additive-subtractive prime sequence or lets name it *Gary's sequence*. It goes like this: let a(0)=2. The next term is defined as smallest prime number which cannot be expressed as the sum and/or difference of any previous terms (note that it means using any combination of plus and minus signs and any number of previous terms).

The sequence begins: 2, 3, 7, 11, 29, 53, 107,...
this sequence is infinite.

My question is:

> Can you describe the behavior of this sequence or maybe you can even create a formula for generating this?

(Remember you are allowed to use each prime exactly once and repetition like 2+2+3+7+11 is absolutely not allowed). For example, 17 is not a member of this sequence because 17 can be expressed as 11+2+7-3 . Also 83 is not a member of this sequence since 83 can be expressed as 11+29-3-7+53 . Also 47 is not a member of this sequence because 47 can be expressed as 29+7+11)

Comment: Interesting. The first 7 terms are similar to [OEIS A138000 "Least prime such that the subsets of { a(1),...,a(n) } sum up to 2^n different values."](http://oeis.org/A138000), discovered by *S. J. Benkoski and P. Erdos, On weird and pseudoperfect numbers, Math. Comp. 28 (1974) 617-623.*

Comment: Actually it is that sequence. I just wrote a program to check and `157 = 107+29+11+7+3`

Comment: OEIS search usually gives helpful inspiration (on arbitrary integer sequences)...

Comment: so the definition on A138000 can be restated/replaced by the definition of mine?

Comment: Apparently. But at first glance I couldn't see how Benkoski and Erdos' statement corresponds to yours.

Comment: I am now retired and I don't blog, but nice to see our work from 1974 is still fresh and usable. Best to you all... Stan Benkoski

Comment: I am only 99% sure that it is the same sequence.Hi Mr Stan !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems identical to:

[OEIS A138000 "Least prime such that the subsets of { a(1),...,a(n) } sum up to 2^n different values."](http://oeis.org/A138000)
http://oeis.org/A138000

Discovered by [S. J. Benkoski and P. Erdos, On weird and pseudoperfect numbers, Math. Comp. 28 (1974) 617-623](http://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/1974-28-126/S0025-5718-1974-0347726-9/)

You're following in the footsteps of giants ;-)

Your next term should be a(8) = 211 (not *157 = 107+29+11+7+3*)

As to the closed-form, OEIS says:

> a(n) > a(n-1) and a(n) <= nextprime(sum(a(i),i=1..n-1)-(-1)^n) ; but
>   in fact a(n) ~ sum(a(i),i=1..n-1)
>
> and thus **a(n) ~ constant*2^n**

where **constant >~ 1.6739958...**

It's probably safest to define a(n) using nearestprime() rather than nextprime(), to avoid precision issues for large n.

As to the name, Benkoski and Erdos didn't give this sequence a name... but I don't think you can call it *Gary's sequence*.

Comment: are you absolutely 100% sure that it is the same sequence?

Comment: @GaryB Yes, have you tried proving it yourself?  It boils down to showing that "all subsets have distinct sums" is equivalent to "each term cannot be expressed as a sum/difference of previous terms".

Comment: damn,what a coincidence!.thanx Wong.

Comment: @ErickWong it is equivalent **if the subsets are disjoint**, even when a(n) < sum of all preceding a(i), which I think they say in OEIS you can prove inductively(?)

Comment: I still have a doubt that it is the same sequence.

Comment: Then compute the next 20 terms and tell us if they match, for starters.